# Поиск в двух таблицах MySQL с объединением результатов

Tags: mysql

Доброе утро!
Возникла такая необходимость:
есть две таблицы

**table1** -  wait_answer | zapros | user_id

**table2** - tel | alias | user_id

Запросом необходимо вывести все значения из **table1** с условием (wait_answer = "1" и zapros = "123") и найти такие же значения в **table2** (table2.tel = table1.zapros, а table2.user_id = table1.user_id). Но тут проблема в том, что в table2 *такой строки может (еще) не быть* - в таком случае вывести ее как **null**.

Уважаемые, подскажите, как грамотно сформировать запрос на MySQL?

Comment: используйте left join

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp если что, то вот вам ссылка раз про LEFT JOIN

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!